# Case Insensitive - GA Summer 19?

Tags: encryption, externalid, platform-encryption, shield-encryption

I have been doing some digging on case Insensitive encryption.  I am reading this:

[Get Exact Matching with Case-Insensitive Deterministic Encryption (Generally Available)](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_security_pe_case_insensitive_deterministic_ga.htm)

And it looks like this feature will be GA with the Summer 19 release. This feature will greatly come in handy, as it will allow us to encrypt fields marked as external IDs. Will this feature (encrypting External IDs) be generally available with that release as well?  I just want to make sure my understanding is correct, before banking on this feature.

Comment: The URL provided in your question does not work. Can you update it so that we get to know what you are talking about?

Comment: Updated @sanketkumar.  My apologies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we're releasing it as GA in Summer '19.  It's already started preview rollout to some sandbox orgs.

Comment: Did you mean Summer '19?

Comment: Yep - sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

In my Summer 19 preview org with Shield Platform Encryption it looks like you can deterministically case insensitive encrypt external id fields

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @cropedy.